# Reindent 100+ files in sublime

Tags: sublimetext2

So I have over 100 html files I would like to Reindent in sublime 2
So far I have binded Reindent to F12
However I do not want to open each file individually then press ctrl-A then F12.
Is there a quicker way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script to loop through the files and run them through jsbeautify or do whatever formatting you'd like.